# Why does a double-tap in UITextView select multiple words like "United States"?

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview

In UITextView if you double-tap the word "United" in the phrase United States, it selects BOTH "United" AND "States".  This works for any phrase that begins with a capital letter.  i.e. Cornell university.

I do not want this behavior and need a way to force it to only select ONE WORD on a double tap.

I have set all the available  settings to NO in my text view:

```
    textView.autocorrectionType = .no
    textView.autocapitalizationType = .none
    textView.spellCheckingType = .no
    textView.smartQuotesType = .no
    textView.smartDashesType = .no
    textView.smartInsertDeleteType = .no`
```

I've added a simple project that demonstrates it here: [www.github.com/KennethFra/SimpleTextView](http://www.github.com/KennethFra/SimpleTextView)

Also a short simulator video demonstrating the behavior.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my simulator (iPhone 14, iOS 16.4). It just highlights "United" or "Cornell" as expected.

Comment: It still works as intended on both iPad and iPhone simulators here, idk.

Comment: Well that's a big clue.  It selects both on all simulators/devices here. What is your locale?

Comment: It selected both words on my iPad Pro (actual device, didn't test the sim).

Comment: @KenFranklin it is italian.

Comment: Select United States on French iPhone 12 mini. May the dictionary consider United State as one word.

Comment: Maybe worth noting... iOS apparently uses some interesting algorithms to select "related" words. I'm guessing it is also (*probably*) somewhat locale-specific. Take a look at this video capture for some examples (all selections are double-taps on single words, using iPad simulator): https://imgur.com/a/Bm4glW4

Comment: I just tried the sample project on simulator, and it did NOT do the multiple word select.  I then built it for device and ran it on my iPad and it DID do the multiple word selection.  It’s something at least.